# os.system for submitting command

Tags: python, lsf

I am using os.system to submit a command to the system.

I.e.,

```
import os
os.system(my_cmd)
```

But I was wondering how could I obtain the output, i.e., let us say i am in the bash and I type in my cmd, I'd get an output of this form:

```
Job <57960787> is submitted to queue <queueq>.
```

How can I, in python, using the os.system(cmd), also obtain the text output, and parse it to obtain the job id, 57960787.

Thanks!

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: You need `pipe()` inter process communication

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is better to use the `subprocess` module documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), example below:

```
import subprocess,re
p = subprocess.Popen('commands',stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
results, errors = p.communicate()
print results
re.search('<(\d+)>', results).group(1) #Cheers, Jon Clements
```

Or you can even use `os.popen` documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen),

```
p_os = os.popen("commands","r")
line = p_os.readline()
print line
re.search('<(\d+)>', line).group(1) #Cheers, Jon Clements
```

Or as John Clements kindly suggested, you can use `subprocess.check_output`, Documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

Comment: First example: `NameError: name 'sub' is not defined` AND `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'PIPE'`. Please verify for the OP.

Comment: May also want to use the new method in 2.7 if applicable which makes this a bit easier: [subprocess.check_output](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output)

Comment: @enginefree and you missed the last part of `re.search('<(\d+)>', s).group(1)` to get the job number ;) (where `s` is the output from the command)

Answer (score 1):

A simple example:

```
>>> import os, sys
>>> cmd = "uname"
>>> b = os.popen(cmd, 'r', 1)
>>> b.read()
'Linux\n'
```

I am running Linux `uname` command.

os.popen() executes command and return a file type object using that you can read command's output.

Answer (score 0):

`os.system` does not return output. So instead you can use the `commands` module.

Example:

```
import commands
my_cmd = 'ls -l'
status, output = commands.getstatusoutput(my_cmd)
print output
```